# Why do we find nature 'beautiful', from an evolutionary perspective?

Tags: evolution

Most people I know find nature beautiful and holidays generally involve a place that has 'natural beauty'.

Comment: I would say that beautiful is pretty subjective and has nothing to do with evolution. It is more something that humans find interesting, probably because of some romantic ideas.

Comment: there is an interesting TED talk about this, basically we don't find all nature beautiful, only certain aspects of nature have universal appeal, the ones that were advantagous for our ancestors like signs of water, food, and climbable trees. https://www.ted.com/talks/denis_dutton_a_darwinian_theory_of_beauty

Answer (score -2):

Bright colors can attract a sexual partner as they are beautiful and are often a sign of good health. So, if you have bright and beautiful colors, you'll attract a partner to reproduce more easily than other and your genes will pass to the next generations. So, some animals are "beautiful" because of sexual selection.
For flowers, bright colors and perfume attract pollinators, so the brighter the better to reproduce. 
Of course, as beauty is all relative, not all flowers or animals are "beautiful" according to humans' tastes. But they suit the environnement the organism lives in and whatever is needed to get to reproduce.
Sexual selection is not the answer to everything you find beautiful but it explains some.

Answer (score -2):

We find valleys pretty. We find mountains pretty. We like sunshine and clouds.

I'd say all these have some advantages. Trees you can climb. In valleys you have protection. From mountains you have a good view across the landscape.

So yes it does make sense that we like nature. We like things that are good for us. Like fertile land and food.